# Case Assignment not fired for Salesforce Outlook

Tags: case, assignment-rules, salesforce-for-outlook

When I create a case from Outlook using Salesforce for outlook into SFDC. The existing case assignment is not fired. The case assignment works as expected when a case is created in Salesforce, provided checking "Assign using active assignment rules". 
Any input in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: is that case is getting created?

Comment: Yes. but the case is not adhering to the case assignment rule.